# How to determine public ip of client in HTTP and HTTPS request?

Tags: java

I have read various blogs and done practically but couldn't get conclusive and full proof way to determine the get client public ip in all possible scenarios.
The configuration on server side is: | F5 <--> Apache web server <--> Tomcat |

In code i first fetch and parse the request header `X-FORWARDED-FOR` to get the left most public ip. If not found i rely on `request.getRemoteAddr()`.

So question is:

1. This works well in some cases but fails when protocol is HTTPS. What can be done in this case?
2. If the `X-Forwarded-For` doesn't have any value then i have to rely on `request.getRemoteAddr()` which always give my server ip. This is because of apache web server which sits in between and `getRemoteAddr` returns the address of the client or last proxy that sent the request. How to overcome this scenario?
3. Is there any other headers on which i should read values apart from `X-forwarded-for`?
4. What all are the other possible cases which should be handled?

Comment: (2) is incorrect. Any intermediate HTTP server or proxy will cause getRemoteAddr() to return its address, but that's because of its *existence,* not because it 'overrides' anything.

Comment: Corrected 2nd point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String forwardedHeader  = servletRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
clientIP =  servletRequest.getRemoteAddr();    

String forwarded = "";
if (forwardedHeader != null && !forwardedHeader.isEmpty())
{
    forwarded = forwardedHeader;

    int commaIdx = forwarded.indexOf(',');
    if (commaIdx > 0)
    {
        clientIP = forwarded.substring(0, commaIdx);
    }

    forwarded = forwarded.replace(',', '|');
}

if (forwarded != null && !forwarded.isEmpty())
{
    clientIP = forwarded;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. It replaces `clientIP`, then continues to work on `forwarded`, then replaces `clientIP` again. Something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Prabha didn't get it, how this will resolve all my queries. Code to fetch ip from header is not my question. Any other ideas?

Comment: We are using same code to log client ip. Servers are also running reverse proxy.

Comment: I don't need to run your code to see that it's wrong. It is self-evidently incorrect, or at least redundant, in the respect I mentioned. If this was a code review, which it is, you just failed it. What's your explanation?